# Check if multi line textbox is empty?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, string

I currently have the following XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="" x:Name="textFeedbackFeedback"
         Margin="11.593,0,29.307,42.96" TextWrapping="Wrap"
         VerticalContentAlignment="Top" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
         Height="92.08" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
```

I have tried using a lot of variations of:

```
if(textFeedbackFeedback.text == "")

if(textFeedbackFeedback.text == null)

if(textFeedbackFeedback.text == string.Empty)

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textFeedbackFeedback.Text))
```

But for some reason it doesn't stop there and continues as if there is data in there, can someone help me out here.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's empty? No carriage returns in there? How about String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text)?

Comment: Please don't put things like "WPF C#" in your titles. That's what tags are for.

Comment: When you look at textFeedbackFeedback.Text in the debugger, what does it show you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textFeedbackFeedback.Text))`

if that doesn't work, try finding out the length of the text, and the integer/ascii values of the chracters in the text.

Comment: Checked length of text, all other methods don't work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the .Trim() function on the text to eliminate any white space that might be in there.